# Inject a date into new entry in firebase db

Tags: javascript, date, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My issue is to inject an actual date when push a data into firebase db.

When user registers himself, following code is being executed:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').push().set(userData);
```

Everything works well. However, I would like to display in user profile the **date** when he created his account.

**I could do it** just with pushing `new Date()` with user data to db, but it will fail if user has an incorrect date on his computer. I would prefer to use actual date coming from server (or firebase?).

**Q**: How to inject actual date into firebase entry?

**Q2**: Is there any date service/function in firebase, which will provide actual date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write a firebase function that detect when a user is created and add the date from the server

```
exports.addDate = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushId}')
    .onCreate(event => {

      const original = event.data.val();

      return event.data.ref.child('date').set(new Date());
    });
```

check this example

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Thank you! Would you like to tell me where to put it? After my code `firebase.database().ref('users').push().set(userData);` or as a callback maybe inside `set`?

Comment: And by the way, do I have to import `functions` because my IDE alerts that it's undefined. Another thing - `original` is declared but never used

Comment: Dropped it under my function, unfortunately didnt work. Anyways, `new Date()` will return a date object from the browser, not from the server, won't it?

Comment: Sorry patrickkx for the delay, the functions are created as a separate concept from your from your regular proyect that need to be upload to firebase, check the getting started with functions https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Answer (score 0):

In case of posterities - all you actually need is:

`firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

you can save it as e.g. `date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,` in your object which u are sending to the db.